# How do we protect our assets url

Tags: php, url

I want to protect my assets url in website:

[www.example.com/assets/image.jpg](http://www.example.com/assets/image.jpg).

I want to show url something like this:

[www.example.com/asdie239487kjjsdfkwjh3erasdfjlkasdf](http://www.example.com/asdie239487kjjsdfkwjh3erasdfjlkasdf)

So I need something that cannot be track my asset url.

Comment: u can fake the path by including another one and inside the fake path include the real one.

Comment: What exactly you mean by `assets` ?

Answer (score 0):

You try that:

```
<?php

// query to database mabye?
$myPath = getImagePath($_GET['id']);

// what kind of image file is that?
$contentType = getContentType($myPath);

// read file content
$img = file_get_contents($myPath);

// here you tell the browser what kind of image is that e.g. jpeg,png,gif...
header("Content-Type: $contentType");

echo $img;

?>
```

you need to define getImagePath and getContentType functions according to your needs.